# Adding a new file to a branch in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have a DEV main line, a production branch and a UAT branch from it, all of which are in the same workspace.  I added a new file to DEV and wanted to add it to UAT but not production.

[This MSDN article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2be97b92-586e-4d9f-b11b-c2d41558a968/how-to-add-a-file-in-a-branch-in-tfs)

Says to do it by merging at the directory level above the file, however what happens if I have several changes in that directory but only want to bring one file across?

I can do it by changeset, date etc but I would like to be able to do it on a file by file basis.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One big point (for me) about TFS is that Changesets are atomic, i.e. when checking in changes to multiple files that all concern the same feature, errors during checkin lead to the whole operation to fail (as opposed to ClearCase, which will result in some files checked in and others not, making the version on the server incomplete). So if you take care to create changesets that contain exactly one feature, it is very easy to merge single features from branch to branch even if they concern hundreds of files, instead of having to figure out which files contain your changes and merging only those. In the real world, of course one feature will consist of multiple changesets with smaller changes, so you should create a Work Item for each feature to assign all changesets concerning that feature to. This way you can easily list all changesets that you need to merge. But I'm starting to ramble...

Anyway, as you rightly guessed, the way to go is merge the parent directory (or even the whole branch), but only the changeset containing the add. All other changesets will be ignored and can be merged the same way later on.

That said, I just looked at my Visual Studio 2010, and it does allow to merge single files just like you merge whole directories. Did you try that? I guess I just assumed you already did ;)

Comment: I tried but when I actually hit merge on the file I got an error back claiming that the file did not exist - or was not mapped or something

Comment: Hm. Are you working with multiple workspaces? Then you need to make sure you choose the correct one in Source Control Explorer and afaik Pending Changes window as well. But I guess merging the directory works fine, so that shouldn't be the issue...

Comment: Both branches are in the same workspace (good point though, I will add that to the question).

Comment: If you get the error message that the file doesn't exist, make sure you have done a "Get latest" on both source and target branches before trying the merge.

Comment: Changesets are indeed atomic in regards to Source Control state - there isn't a state where only part of a changeset is in. However, you merge by file revisions, which *may* be determined by changeset (VS "Merge" UI does that), but may also not. I understand that in some systems like Mercurial and GIT Changesets are indeed true first-class objects.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS, you can only merge according to branch relationships. Yours are `Dev => Production => UAT`, so you can't merge Dev=>UAT without going through Production.

Options:

1. **Not Recommended**: Merge Dev=>Production, merge Production=>UAT, then rollback Production.
   **Why not**: You'll have problems when you merge the entire Dev=>Production again.
2. Do a baseless merge of the file(s) Dev=>UAT. I think Visual Studio doesn't have that in Source Control Explorer, but you could do it in "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012", using `tf merge /baseless`.
3. Just edit the file(s) in UAT and bring over its content from Dev.

In either 2 or 3, beware that once you've merged one branch to Production, you'll have a (possibly auto-resolvable) merge conflict when merging the other.

Comment: We were using 2012 for this merge so we performed the baseless merge via the MSDEV GUI.  This is the way we have handled our software for years, long before we started using TFS.  We only merge fixes and specific enhancements once the branch has been made.